# Kafka standby replica clarity sought

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, standby

I'm after some clarification on how Kafka standby replicas work for some piece of mind!

Given this scenario;

A Kafka streams application;

- reading from a source topic with 10 partitions
- writing to a sink topic with 6 partitions.
- rocksdb session state changelog
- hosted in docker with two replicas running num.standby.replicas set to 1

The idea is that if one pod does down the other pod will take over processing immediately...as least that is what I thought having the num.standby.replicas set did.

What I am seeing is when initially starting up, only one pod is processing traffic. This is what I'd expect, one pod processing traffic and the other pod just keeping state in case of fail over.

However, if I restart the a pod, both pods start processing traffic equally.

Is there any information online which could clarify how standby replicas are meant to work?..or is this expected behaviour?

J

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is by design. Both pods will do 50% of processing and the standby tasks are assigned "reversed". Ie, if pod A host active task 0_0, the corresponding standby task 0_0 will be hosted by pod B.

Thus, whenever one pods fails, only 50% of tasks are "migrated", ie, if pod A fails, all standbys of pod B will be "promoted" as active, and pod B will now do all processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What @Jill asked is interesting-shouldnt initially when both pods start pick up different tasks-and not only one picking them both? Also is there a scenario when pod2 fails, 50% of the tasks are migrated-which means pod1 runs everything. Does at any point pod2 take over a part of the work? Or it does not until pod1 fails. Thanks!

Comment: On startup there is a race condition -- both pods would never startup at the exact same time. When the first pod connects to the broker, it think it's the only one (it cannot know that a second one is started in parallel). Thus, it first gets all tasks assigned, and when the second pod startups later tasks would be migrated to distribute load (there is a cluster config `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms` that allows you to tell the first pod to actually wait for others to join -- this can help that each pod get (only) some tasks assigned right away, but also implies higher startup latency).

Comment: Not sure if understand the second question. If pod2 fails, well it failed and cannot do any work... all its tasks would be migrated to pod1. -- Or course, the moment pod2 recovers, 50% of the tasks would be migrated away from pod1 to pod2 again to distribute the load (similar to the startup cases). -- Each time a pod start and joins the group, or fails, a task redistribution happens.

Comment: Regarding `the second pod startups later tasks would be migrated to distribute load`  - I assume this happens automatically as part of Kafka/KafkaStreams trying to distribute the load? And this includers `promoting` the new one to have an active task? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any update on that Matthias? Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure if I can follow? What update?

Comment: On my last question?

Comment: `I assume this happens automatically as part of Kafka/KafkaStreams trying to distribute the load` -> yes.